# Do I need a SFTP if I use an online IDE?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ftp, ide, cloud

I've only been using Filezilla over the past few years to upload simple landing page templates to my hosting company. I've now created a new Django project on Google Cloud Platform that comes with pre-installed LAMP (P for python) Package, so far neither a  Cpanel nor FTP credentials have been mentioned anywhere, only SSH, which confused me very much.

But, I quickly figured that I would need an IDE to start building a web application.There are many options including local IDEs (Vcode, Pycharm, Eclipse) and Cloud IDEs (Replit, Cloud9). I decided to go with C9 as it offers a GCP integration and it's free.

AWS Cloud9, a cloud-based IDE lets you write, run, and debug your code with just a browser, you don’t need to install files or configure any development machine to start new projects.

So, is there any reason to use a SFTP to transfer or upload files?

Comment: FTP is not setup on VM instances. SSH/SFTP is. FTP is not secure. SFTP is. You must decide which is best to use for your use case. I recommend learning how to use SSH and SFTP for connections, file transfers and development.

Comment: I guess I wouldn't need to if I integrated AWS Cloud9 with my Google Cloud Platform "Django" project, right? If not, I must be missing something then.

Answer (score 1):

As default Linux VM instances from Google Cloud Cloud Platform has OpenSSH installed so you could use SCP or SFTP to transfer files here is the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files) to learn how to transfer files to the VM Instances, Unless your online IDE has the ssh-keys authentication with SFTP to transfer files like this [online editor](https://shiftedit.net/about), you will require a SFTP client to copy files.